# Different currents in the phases of a Multiphase Buck Converter

Tags: control-engineering, simulation

I am a student of electrical and computer engineering and am currently working on a project that involves the study of a Multiphase Buck Converter or Synchronous Buck Converter. Thus, in simulating the circuit I noticed that the inductances do not have the same mean current value, which is supposed to be 3 A. It's probably worth mention that the MOSFET1 and the MOSFET3 also have different current max values. To simulate the circuit I used PLECS and this is the waveform of the inductors currents (IL1 and IL2), the circuit diagram and the waveforms of the MOSFET (MOSFET1 and MOSFET3) currents.

[image: Waveform of the inductors currents]

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image: MOSFET 1 & 3 Current waveforms]

The output current value (Io) is the sum of the currents of the inductances (IL1 and IL2) which is 6 A, as expected, but I don't understand why one inductance carries more current than another.

If someone can explain to me why this happens and how to correct it, I would appreciate it.

Thanks for your time,

José Alves

Comment: I strongly recommend migrating this question to electronics.stackexchange.com.  This site is a general engineering site tending toward mechanical and civil engineering; electronics.stackexchange.com is exactly what it says -- electronics.

Comment: Whether it's migrated or not, please _edit your question_ to say whether PLECS uses idealized components (it looks like it does) and whether you modeled the inductors as having resistance.  The short answer to your question (which I, or someone, will expand upon once the question is migrated) is that if all the parts are lossless then there's nothing to control the _difference_ between the average inductor currents -- just the _sum_.

Comment: Why should they be the same? it looks like you are running each phase on a fixed duty cycle, but out of phase. The first time the second inductor "turns on" it's going to have a lower voltage across it because the output capacitor is already partly charged. And without active control, it can stay that way.